# Android Service onStartCommand flags

Tags: android, service

Если я правильно понимаю, то за перезапуск сервиса после "убийства" отвечают флаги, возвращаемые в onStartCommand. Для проверки использовал простейший сервис:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TestService onCreate");
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TestService onDestroy");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TestService onStartCommand")
    readFlags(flags);
    MyRun mr = new MyRun(startId);
    new Thread(mr).start();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

void readFlags(int flags) {
    switch (flags) {
        case START_FLAG_REDELIVERY:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_FLAG_REDELIVERY");
            break;
        case START_FLAG_RETRY:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "START_FLAG_RETRY");
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Flag: " + flags);
    }
}

class MyRun implements Runnable {

    int startId;

    public MyRun(int startId) {
        this.startId = startId;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Run#" + startId + " create");
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Run#" + startId + " start");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop();
    }

    void stop() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Run#" + startId + " end, stopSelfResult("
                + startId + ") = " + stopSelfResult(startId));
    }
}
```

который запускал на трёх устройствах (4.1.2, 4.4.2, 6.0.1). Но после "убийства" процесса, сервис перезапускался только на одном из устройств, выдавая лог

```
D/myLogs: TestService onCreate
 D/myLogs: TestService onStartCommand
 D/myLogs: START_FLAG_REDELIVERY
 D/myLogs: MyRun#1 create
 D/myLogs: MyRun#1 start
 D/myLogs: MyService onDestroy
 D/myLogs: MyRun#1 end, stopSelfResult(1) = true
```

На остальных устройствах сервис умирал с концами. Аналогичная ситуация с другими "липкими" флагами. Я неправильно понимаю механизм перезапуска службы или проблема в чём-то другом?

Comment: Попробуйте изменить return START_REDELIVER_INTENT на return START_STICKY